# Url ending in xn--com-6na

Tags: firefox

I'm using the firefox browser under a proxy. Today I entered an url (the google project www.movikantirevo.com), it translated to the url
www.movikantirevo.xn--com-6na. It never happened before, and after a little time it returned back to normal. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [Internationalized Domain Name (IDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), which allows non-ASCII characters to be used in domain names via [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encoding. IDN fragments begin with an ASCII Compatible Encoding prefix `xn--`, which signifies "eXtensible Name".

The value you specified translates to `comù`, or `&#x63;&#x6f;&#x6d;&#xf9;` in HTML encoding.

As to *why* this happened - I have no idea. The domain doesn't resolve for me. Perhaps it was a redirection glitch on their end.

Comment: this happened because the ù is near my enter key, although I couldn't find anything about it googling. Many thanks

Comment: Ah, that explains it then!